# `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsuserdefaults, appirater

I want to save some user preferences, but

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

just returns `nil`.

[iOS-Developper Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says, that this should return the existing shared defaults object or create one if none exists... What am I missing?

I also use [Appirater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater) and there all this stuff seems also not to work...

This code gets called when the user pushes a button...

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int index = ([defaults integerForKey:@"BackgroundColorSpecifier"]+ 1)%self.backgroundColors.count;
[defaults setInteger:index forKey:@"BackgroundColorSpecifier"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

This gets called in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[standardDefaults registerDefaults:@{@"BackgroundColorSpecifier": @0}];
[standardDefaults synchronize];
```

When I debug this code snippets the green "position-indicator" jumps around in a very strange manner...

I don't have any clue, whats going on... Please help!

Comment: how did you find that `defaults` is nil ? Did you put a breakpoint on this line ?

Comment: Yes... and it is nil everywhere else where `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` is called...

Comment: I do not think defaults is nil. How do you check that ? I think you are trying to get a key from NSUserDefaults which not exists and which is nil.

Comment: So you are right, nothing gets logged... But look at this: [screenshot]{https://www.dropbox.com/s/7k5kup9iaa9wihw/Screenshot%202013-12-19%2010.50.13.png}

Comment: Is the Build Configuration = "Release" or "Debug"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is far more likely to be a problem with the debugger than anything else, particularly with your other issues. I've seen similar things in my own projects but don't have a reliable way of clearing it out other than the usual restart / clean options.

NSLogs will usually give more consistent results than the debugger if the debugger is having an off day.

NSUserDefaults isn't broken. We'd have heard about it by now.

Answer (score -2):

you can use this function to log you userDefaults dic

```
 - (void)logCache
    {
        NSDictionary * dic = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
        NSString *bundleId = [dic  objectForKey: @"CFBundleIdentifier"];
        NSUserDefaults *appUserDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] init];
        NSDictionary *cacheDic = [appUserDefaults persistentDomainForName: bundleId];
        NsLog(@"cacheDic::%@",cacheDic);
    }
```